# Memory Error with array of struct reading a bin file

Tags: c, file, struct

im trying to read input.txt file which is a bin file. It kinda works, beside the facts that when im reading the file, if i print what i read inside the loop where i copy my data inside my structure, it shows the proper values. If i do not print the datas inside the loop, and i print them in another function after finishing the loop (without modifying the structure) i get an error where some data i printed before become different.
Im reading i file where there is a register number, a name of a person, month, year, wage.

```
Matr    Nome    MM      AA      Stipendio
300     Maria   9       1999    1050
301     Luigi   5       2000    1200
309     Marco   8       2000    1220
306     Marta   7       1998    1100
306     Marta   7       1998    1100
300     Maria   9       2001    0
0       Luigi   5       2000    1200
309     Marco   8       2000    1220
306     Marta   7       1998    1100
309     Marco   1220
306     Marta   1342
```

Thats an example of what i am speaking about.

This is the file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/89s0kw13jf0fpr5/input.txt?dl=0

This is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct n{
    int mat;
    char nome[20];
    int mese;
    int anno;
    int stip;
}Dipendente;
typedef Dipendente *dip;

void  readfile(dip h, int dim);
void printStip(dip h, int dim);
void increasestip(dip h, int dim);

int main(){
    int dim = 4;
    dip h = NULL;
    h= malloc(sizeof(h)*dim);
    readfile(h,dim);
    increasestip(h,dim);
    printStip(h,dim);
    return 0;
}
//printing people with more than cetain wage
void printStip(dip h, int dim){
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < dim; i++){
        if(h[i].stip >1200){
            printf("%d\t%s\t%d\n",h[i].mat,h[i].nome,h[i].stip);
        }
    }
}
// increasing wage if hired before a certain date.
void increasestip(Dipendente *h, int dim){
    int i ;
    for(i  = 0 ; i < dim ; i++){
       // thats where data printed are messed up
        printf("%d\t%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",h[i].mat,h[i].nome,h[i].mese,h[i].anno,h[i].stip);

        if(h[i].anno < 2000){
                h[i].stip  +=(h[i].stip*0.22);
                }
        else if(h[i].anno == 2000 && h[i].mese < 5){
            h[i].stip +=(h[i].stip*0.22);

        }
    }
}

//reading file function
void readfile(dip h, int dim){
    FILE *fptr = NULL;

    if((fptr = fopen("input.txt","rb"))==NULL){
        printf("Errore nell\'apertura del file\n");
        exit(0);

    }
    else{
        int i =0;
        int nbytes;
        Dipendente t= {0,{0},0,0,0};
        printf("Matr\tNome\tMM\tAA\tStipendio\n");
        while(!feof(fptr)){
                fread(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fptr);
                strncpy(h[i].nome,t.nome,strlen(t.nome)+1);
                h[i].mat = t.mat;
                h[i].mese = t.mese;
                h[i].anno = t.anno;
                h[i].stip = t.stip;
 // thats where i get proper print
                printf("%d\t%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",h[i].mat,h[i].nome,h[i].mese,h[i].anno,h[i].stip);

                i++;
        }      
    }
}
```

Im new to linking files with dropbox so if the link doesnt work tell me.
About reading bin file, im new to that too but it seems to work, fread seems to work well.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(h)*dim)` -> `malloc(sizeof(*h)*dim)`

Comment: can i ask you why it should be *h? Anyway thank you that was the problem eheh

Comment: `sizeof(h)` is `sizeof(Dipendente *)` which is clearly not what you want. The syntax `sizeof(*h)` gives the size of the type that the pointer points to which is `sizeof(Dipendente)` as needed.